# Create a group by and display a sequence number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to create an SQL query that can satisfy the following requirement. Turn this table:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

The trick or challenge is to obtain the order of the cycle using the chronological order of the event type timestamp. I have tried different combination of ORDER BY with COUNT (*) but I haven't had any success. Can it be achieved using SQL? Any help that can lead me to the right path is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you are starting over based on the first six characters of `event_type`.  So, you need `partition by`:

```
select t.*
       row_number() over (partition by left(event_type, 6) order by timestamp) as cycle_id
from t;
```

EDIT:

If your numbering is based on the month:

```
select t.*
       row_number() over (partition by year(timestamp), month(timestamp) order by timestamp) as cycle_id
from t;
```

Comment: It looks to me more like he's starting over based on the Month of the timestamp, but it's likely the two fields are related.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . That is a reasonable interpretation as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data that you posted I think that the grouping you want is for the part of the column `EventType` before the underscore:

```
select 
  *,
  row_number() over (
    partition by left([Event Type], charindex('_', [Event Type]) - 1) 
    order by [TimeStamp])
  ) [Cycle Id]
from tablename
```